# Should questions be edited out of answers?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I came across this [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/280035/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-that-allows-us-to-refers-to-whats-around-an-issue-pro/280037#280037) that repeated the contents of the [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/280035/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-that-allows-us-to-refers-to-whats-around-an-issue-pro) verbatim. I made a [suggested edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/118913) that essentially removed the question from the answer.

However, the edit was rejected by the post author on the grounds that it didn't improve the readability of the answer

> The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.

Obviously, I disagree (hence my suggested edit).

I raised a moderator flag asking for the edit to be pushed through, but was told that this is not something that warrants moderator intervention, which seems reasonable. It was also suggested that I raise this on Meta, so here goes:

What does the community think about questions in answers? Should they be edited out? If so, and the author disagrees, what should be done in that case?

Comment: Might be it's too late at night for me, but I think your edit was perfectly fine and in fact it's something I would want editors to do.

Comment: When a question is very complicated and you'd have to otherwise scroll back up to reference the original question, sure, include it. The other 95% of the time, answers do better without repeating the question.

Comment: Haha. My question is like an open highway. I never rejected the sugested edit how low the rep the suggesting user has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do think moderator intervention is the easiest way out of this. I've approved the edit (♦ moderators can [do this for a while now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/295232)) and left a comment. The author responded with a plausible reason for rejecting the edit; it turns out they do that in order to avoid downvotes when the *question* is edited and their post does no longer answer it; such questions are [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/295232) and the Stack Exchange way of avoiding those situations is [rolling back the edit to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177177/295232).